# Major Mongoose Issue - Wrong collection being selected

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

```
var Checkin, CheckinSchema;
CheckinSchema = require('../models/schemas/CheckinSchema').CheckinSchema;
Checkin = mongoose.model('Checkin', CheckinSchema, "checkin_" + targetDoc._id);
Checkin.find(query, function(err, checkins) {
  return console.log(checkins.length);
});
```

That's my code (at least the relevant part). The issue is that the `targetDoc._id` changes which means the collection that is being accessed changes. The problem is that it always selects a particular collection, `checkin_abc` instead of `checkin_def`. Does anyone have any possible insight regarding this? Are underscores a problem for `Mongoose`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, that drove me nuts! The answer is you need **unique** names for the collection!!!